# Why is my shared library much bigger when compiled as position independent code?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm writing a shared library which statically links SDL2. Thus, I compile both SDL2 and my shared library with `-fPIC`. I've noticed that without using `-fPIC` the final shared library size is about 940 kilobytes whereas with `-fPIC` the final shared library size is about 1.4 megabytes.

Why is the shared library so much bigger when compiled with `-fPIC` than when compiled without `-fPIC`?

Tests were done on a Raspberry Pi 2 so the target architecture is either ARMv7A or ARMv8(A).

Comment: Sidenote: "the target architecture is arm" -> "ARM". And ARM has a lot of very different architectures. ARMv7A != ARMv7M != ARMv8 etc. Your question cannot be answered, library-size != code-size for example.

Comment: Well, I mentioned that I did the tests on a Raspberry Pi 2 so it should be clear that I'm talking about armv7a. I don't understand why this question cannot be answered. All I want to know is why there is a size explosion when using `-fPIC`. I think that is a very clear question.

Comment: There are two very different ARM cores used for the Rasberry Pi 2: Cortex-A7 and A53. The A53 is not ARMv7A, but V8(A) actually! And that is not the only problem with your question

Comment: I've rephrased the question. Is it answerable now? If not, how about some constructive criticism? Just downvoting doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Your edit did not make it anythink better for this site. I gave you a lot of relevant hints; if you don't undrstand them, how about some research? You don't learn programming in an hour or by being spoon-fed. What do you expect? crystal balls? Check the machine code, what does objdump show which is not clear? What is the problem you have checking it yourself? Learn about use the tools you have and use them, they can tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Depending on the architecture, there is overhead to making code position-independent. I don't think a 30% increase is cause for alarm. If you're really curious, build a minimal library in both forms, and look at the disassembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: there is overhead involved with making code position-independent.

In non-position-independent code, the compiler can simply emit references to fixed addresses when accessing global data. With PIC, there is typically a Global Offset Table (GOT) involved; the compiler has to emit additional code to access the GOT first. The same goes for references to other functions; with PIC, these calls go through the Procedure Lookup Table (PLT).

This additional level of indirection causes a necessary size increase.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is an accurate answer to a simple question.

Comment: I upvoted it. I'm actually completely puzzled about the fuss that was generated by my question. I don't even know where all the hostility and aggression comes from. But thanks a lot for your answer! Shows that there is still a spirit of helpfulness on Stack Overflow instead of just telling all people to RTFM. Of course 50% of the questions on SO could probably be solved by RTFM but I still think it's slightly overkill to tell people to "check the machine code" (Olaf) when they basically just want to know whether PIC is larger than non-PIC. As you said, it is a simple question.